# Get count of Groupby (Sqlalchemy)

Tags: sqlalchemy, postgresql-9.1

I am new to SQLAlchemy and need some help with a query.

I have a usertraffic table with 200000 records, it has user_id and a date-time stamp with the time of their visit.

I am using this query to group user by visit and show count

session.query(UserTraffic.user_id,func.count(UserTraffic.X)).group_by(UserTraffic.user_id).all()

It returns data as (UserId and no of visits):
(49386, 1L), (49387, 2L), (49388, 5L), (49389, 3L), (49390, 4L), (49391, 3L), (49392, 2L)

What I want to get is to get the count of these, example:
(x,y), (1,1), (2,2), (3,2),(4,1),(5,1)
[as no of users who have only 1 visit is 1, and no of users who have 3 visits is 2)

Where x is no of repeat visits and y is the no of of users with repeat visits.

Can you please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add another `GROUP BY` on top of it. Easiest is to use [`subquery`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.subquery):

```
subq = (session
        .query(UserTraffic.user_id, func.count(UserTraffic.X).label("cnt_X"))
        .group_by(UserTraffic.user_id)
        ).subquery("subq")

q = (session
        .query(subq.c.cnt_X, func.count(subq.c.user_id).label("cnt_users"))
        .group_by(subq.c.cnt_X)
        .order_by(subq.c.cnt_X)
        ).all()
```